# Can I map multiple query string values to a single controller (object) parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, query-string, model-binding

I'm building an ASP.NET Web API REST service.

The calls (URLs) I have to process are fixed by another party and have numerous query string parameters.

Rather than have my controller take a dozen parameters, is there any way that I can map the query parameters to an object and pass that through to the controller?

I know that I could access them within the controller through GetQueryNameValuePairs, but I was wondering if there was a way to use data binding in this fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET Web API seems to require the use of the [FromUri] when passing a model object to a controller. For example:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromUri] MyModel model) { ... }
```

See this [MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

Define a model, e.g.:

```
public class InputModel
{
    public string Param1 { get; set; }
    public string Param2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then adjust your action:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(InputModel model) { ... }
```

Much like MVC, the API controllers support *Model Binding*, there is an infrastructure in place to handle this, which itself is extensible. I'd google for examples of ASP.NET MVC Model Binding.

Comment: I tried this, but my model parameter is always null. I have an "orderNumber" in query string and an OrderNumber property in my model class, but it doesn't seem to bind. Not sure if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Binds fine when I use a standard MVC controller.

Comment: Seems you need to use the [FromUri] attribute - e.g. public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromUri] MyModel model).

Comment: Some details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx

Comment: This doesn't work if you want to accept both POST and GET operations. You can use [FromUri] but then it'll only work from the querystring not from PostBuffer or for raw data. 
This is a major downer for Web API actually - the flexibility is much less than what MVC provides in ModelBinding.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply create a query string parser:

```
protected IDictionary<string, string> GetQueryParameters(string queryString)
{
    var retval = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (var item in queryString.TrimStart('?').Split(new[] {'&'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        var split = item.Split('=');
        retval.Add(split[0], split[1]);
    }
    return retval;
}
```

And then from controller call:

```
public class DummyController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string SayHello(string name="")
    {
        var q = GetQueryParameters(Request.RequestUri.Query);

        return string.Format("Hello {0}", name);
    }
}
```